# Is It safe to issue multiple async_send_to to in one udp socket?

Tags: boost-asio

I am writing an udp broadcast server with boost::asio. Udp packets will be received from one source side and broadcasted to multiple destinations. Is it safe to do something like this in a single thread?

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket s;
MyHandler handler; // do nothing handler
MyBuffer buffer; //  buffer is allocated on heap and managed by smart ptr
...

s.async_send_to(buffer, destination1, handler);
s.async_send_to(buffer, destination2, handler);
s.async_send_to(buffer, destination3, handler);
```

Or should I use blocking send_to instead? Or should I chain them, i.e, calling the second async_send_to in the completion handler of the first async_send_to?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says :

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

If the buffer is allocated on the stack (i.e., it is defined in the same block where the async_send is called) this is most likely broken. Because the call so async_send won't block and as soon as you return from this code snippet, the memory will be deallocated. You can make 'buffer'  a class property to make sure that it remains valid for as long as you need it. But if the buffer is on the heap then you're fine, and the code will work as it is.

Comment: You are right, but my concern here is not about the lifetime of buffer(it's allocated on heap and managed by referece counted smart pointer). Rather, i want to confirm whether issuing multiple pending async_send_to operations on the same UDP socket is legal, illegal or undefined behavior? As long as I know, it's unsafe to issue multiple async_read operations on a same TCP socket even in a single thread because async_read is a composed operation thus the underlying data received may be interleaved among the multpile operations.